# Solving $\ln\frac{a}{b}=\left(c-\frac{1}{2}d^{2}\right)T+d\sqrt{T}\cdot x$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to go from

$$\ln\frac{a}{b}=\left(c-\frac{1}{2}d^{2}\right)T+d\sqrt{T}\cdot x$$

to

$$x=\frac{\ln\frac{a}{b}-\left(c-\frac{1}{2}d^{2}\right)T}{d\sqrt{T}}$$

so I basically need to write the expression in terms of $x$. I have learned how to rationalize the denominator, but I have no idea how to get to the result shown (in terms of $x$).

Comment: You got confused by looking at some large terms, not trying to sound bad or anything but try for significant amount of time and if you can't find a solution after that then you may ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ln(\frac{a}{b})=(c-\frac{1}{2}d^2)T+d\sqrt{T} \cdot x$

Subtract $(c-\frac{1}{2}d^2)T$ on both sides

$\ln(\frac{a}{b})-(c-\frac{1}{2}d^2)T = d\sqrt{T} \cdot x$

Divide by $d\sqrt{T}$ (assuming d,T $\neq 0$)

$\frac{\ln(\frac{a}{b})-(c-\frac{1}{2}d^2)T}{d\sqrt{T}} = x$